# Find a set of keywords in a string

Tags: python, string

```
def check_links(hrefs_list):
    check_str = ['NEWS',
                 'MEDIA',
                 'news',
                 'media',
                 'News',
                 'Media',
                 'press',
                 'releases',
                 'Press',
                 'Releases',
                 'PRESS',
                 'RELEASES']
    relevant_links=list()
    for i in range(len(hrefs_list)):
        if hrefs_list[i].find(check_str)!= -1:
            relevant_links.append(hrefs_list[i])
        else:
            continue
    return relevant_links
```

check_links(hrefs_list) accepts a list of href values. I want to go to each href value and check if it contains any of the keyword present in the check_str list. If it does, I want to store it to a fresh list, otherwise not.
But when I run this function it gives an error : **if hrefs_list[i].find(check_str)!= -1:
TypeError: must be str, not list**

How do I solve this ?

Comment: What is the type of `hrefs_list[i]` ?

Comment: @rootkonda it's a string

Comment: Could you edit the question to provide a sample ```hrefs_list``` and its expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
def check_links(hrefs_list):
    check_str = ['NEWS',
                 'MEDIA',
                 'news',
                 'media',
                 'News',
                 'Media',
                 'press',
                 'releases',
                 'Press',
                 'Releases',
                 'PRESS',
                 'RELEASES']
    relevant_links=list()
    for i in range(len(hrefs_list)):
        if hrefs_list[i] in check_str:
            relevant_links.append(hrefs_list[i])
        else:
            continue
    return relevant_links
```

Example:

```
hrefs_list = ['NEWS',
              'MEDIA',
              'news',
              'others']
check_links(hrefs_list)
```

Output:

```
['NEWS', 'MEDIA', 'news']
```

Comment: for i in range(len(hrefs_list)):
        if any([x in hrefs_list[i] for x in check_str]) :
        
            relevant_links.append(hrefs_list[i])

Comment: used this and it works !

Comment: the code that you wrote will only work if it's an exact match. What if hrefs_list was ['www.example.com/news/', 'www.example.com/media-releases/', 'www.example.com/about-us']
then the code you wrote won't work.